# Without calling polym(), how can I count the number of interactions it will return?

Tags: r, polynomials

How can I count number of interactions `poly` will return?

If I have two variables, then the number of interactions `poly` will return in function of degree is given by:

```
degree <- 2

dim(poly(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), degree = degree))[2]
```

That is the same as:

```
(degree^2+3*degree)/2
```

Is there anyway to count the number of interactions depending on the number of degree and variables (in case I use more than two)?

Comment: What are you asking? Perhaps including some sort of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Math result from combinations**

Suppose you have `p` variables, the number of interactions associated with degree `d` is computed by:

```
fd <- function (p, d) {
  k <- choose(p, d)
  if (d > 1) k <- k + p * sum(choose(p-1, 0:(d-2)))
  return(k)
  }
```

The function `poly` (actually `polym` in this case), with `p` input variables and a `degree = D`, will construct interactions from `degree = 1` up to `degree = D`. So the following function counts it:

```
fD <- function (p, D) {
   if (D < 1) return(0)
   component <- sapply(1:D, fd, p = p)
   list(component = component, ncol = sum(component))
   }
```

The entry `component` gives the number of interaction for each degree  from `1` to `D`, and `ncol` component gives total number of interactions.

---

A quick test:

```
a <- runif(50)
b <- runif(50)
c <- runif(50)
d <- runif(50)
X <- poly(a, b, c, d, degree = 3)
ncol(X)
# 34

fD(4, 3)
# component
# [1] 4  10  20
#
# ncol
# [1] 34
```

---

**How R does this?**

The first few lines of the source code for `polym` explains how R addresses this problem. An `expand.grid` is first called to get all possible interactions, then a `rowSums` is called to compute the degree of all available interactions. Finally, a filter is applied to retain only interactions terms with degree between `1` and `D`.

Answer (score 0):

More than three years later I had to work with degree >=3 polynomials.  Unfortunately @李哲源 solution fails for degrees larger than 3. I could, however, build two solutions:

**Expand Grid Solution**

This method emulates `polym` original behavior, which is not very elegant for our purposes but is a natural benchmark.

```
expand_grid_solution <- function(nd, degree){
  z <- do.call(expand.grid, c(rep.int(list(0:degree), nd), 
                              KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = FALSE))
  s <- rowSums(z)
  ind <- 0 < s & s <= degree
  z <- z[ind, , drop = FALSE]
  s <- s[ind]
  return(length(s))
}
```

**Combination with repetion solution**

```
combination_with_repetition <- function(n, r){
  factorial(r+n-1)/(factorial(n-1)*factorial(r))
} 

poly_elements <- function(n, d) {
  x <- sapply(1:d, combination_with_repetition, n = n) 
  return(sum(x))
}
```

---

A quick test:

```
mapply(expand_grid_solution, c(2,2,2,3,3,3,4), c(2,3,4,2,3,4,4))
#[1]  5  9 14  9 19 34 69

mapply(poly_elements, c(2,2,2,3,3,3,4), c(2,3,4,2,3,4,4))
#[1]  5  9 14  9 19 34 69
```